# Why does the `title_text` argument of `fig.update_layout` appear not to be working for Plotly table in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab

I'm showing a Pandas DataFrame in a Plotly Figure Factory table, and the arguments in `fig.update_layout` are all working as expected except for `title_text` (example [here](https://plotly.com/python/figure-factory-table/)).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'member': 'A B C D E F G'.split(' '),
    'amount': [515, 45, 315, 321, 43, 244, 433]
})

fig = ff.create_table(df)

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Titletext'
    autosize=False,
    width=150*df.shape[1],
    height=40*df.shape[0],
)

fig.show()
```

This generates the table with the right cell sizes, but no title *showing in the Jupyter Notebook output*.

[image]

Comment: Your code seems okay from a first glance. You may need to adjust margin. Check this out: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2795. `fig.update_layout({'margin': {'t': 50}})`.

Comment: That's it! Want to repost as answer? I'm also trying to figure out how to shift the position of the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to adjust the margins of the plot.
A similar issue was tagged on github: https://www.github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2795.

The solution: `fig.update_layout({'margin': {'t': 50}})`. This means create a 50px margin from the top of the figure, so that the title isn't "cutoff" from the plot.